# Ruby On Rails @gym.All API Isn't Returning All Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a postgresql database with a table called gyms.

It has several fields and a one to one relationship with another table. Its migration file looks like this:

```
class CreateGyms < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :gyms do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :address
      t.string :city
      t.string :country

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I have created several rows for the table and according to my postgresql table they are fine. However, when I try to GET the json the name, city, address and country variables are not being returned.

The controller looks like this:

```
class GymsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_gym, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /gyms
  # GET /gyms.json
  def index
    @gyms = Gym.all
  end

  # GET /gyms/1
  # GET /gyms/1.json
  def show
  end
```

Why are only these values being returned?

```
{"id":1,"created_at":"2017-12-09T09:18:48.993Z","updated_at":"2017-12-09T09:18:48.993Z","url":"https://okuapp.com/gyms/1.json"}
```

And how can i make it so that all values are returned? (name, city, etc)

Before when i only had one table and there were no associations, this was not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had changed my schema for the gyms table but i had not updated the json builder files.

Updated those and fixed the problem.